# How to select some rows from a Pyspark dataframe column and add it to a new dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have 10 dataframes,`df1...df10` with 2 columns:

### `df1`

`id | 2011_result`,

### `df2`

`id | 2012_result`,
...
...

### `df3`

`id| 2018_result`

I want to do select some ids with `2011_result` values less than a threshold.

```
 sample_ids=df1['2011_result']<threshold].sample(10)['id'].values
```

After this, I need to select the values for other columns from all other data frames for the list.

Something like this:

`df2[df2['id'].isin(sample_ids)]['2012_result']`
`df3[df3['id'].isin(sample_ids)]['2013_result']`

Could you please help out?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can filter with:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sample_ids=df1.filter(F.col("2011_result") < threshold)
```

Then you can use `left_anti` join to filter out `df2`, `df3`, etc:

```
df2 = df2.join(sample_ids.select("id"), on="id", how="left_anti")
```